# in Laravel livewire, how To check validation, if an input is unique based on another unique filed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In Laravel 10, How to make a rule or validation for this condition.

I have two inputs: **order_number** and **part_number**, we can have the same **order_number** but different **part_number**, for example:

order_number = 123, part_number = aba

order_number = 123, part_number = cddd

order_number = 123, part_number = fff

but
order_number = 123, part_number = fff

is not accepted because with this order_number = 123 is exists already part_number = fff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

An even cleaner approach is to add `unique:table_name` to your validation string.

for instance if you want to make sure that the part_number doesn't exist in the orders database, you may do the following:

```php
'part_number' => 'unique:orders'
```

in case you're field name on the frontend doesn't match the column name in the backend you may specify that as well.

```php
'part_number' => 'unique:orders,partNumber'
```

## Original Answer

You need to manually add an item to the [Laravel error bag](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation) only if a DB check is met:

```php
if(Orders::where('part', $this->part_number)->count() > 0)
{
    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('part_number', 'Part number already exists');
}
```

depending on your livewire setup, this may also work:

```
if(Orders::where('part', $this->part_number)->count() > 0)
{
   $this->addError([key], [message]) // Replace key and message with your own key and message
}
```

More info on the topic can also be found [here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/validation#manually-controlling-validation-errors).

Comment: so thanks. I use Livewire 3 so this can be:
        if(Post::where('order_number', $this->order_number)->count() > 0)
        {
            Validator::make(
                    ['part_number' => $this->part_number],
                    ['part_number' => 'unique:posts,part_number'],
            )->validate();
        }